# How to add key to React Component object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make tree style HTML. (with React)

This is Node class and It contains child nodes.

```
class Node extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            children: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <div id={this.props.id} className="person">
                   <div className="info">
                       <div className="name">{this.props.name}</div>
                   </div>
                   <div className="childrenWrap">
                       <div className="children">
                           {this.state.children}
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>;
    }

    addChild(node) {
         this.setState({children: this.state.children.concat(node)});
    }
}

//////////////

let tree = document.querySelector("#tree");
let root = ReactDom.render(<Person id="root" name="A" />, tree);
root.addChild(<Person id="child1" name="B" />);
root.addChild(<Person id="child2" name="C" />);
root.addChild(<Person id="child3" name="D" />);
```

but, this code will occur Warning 'Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.'.

So I add `key={this.props.id}` next of `id={this.props.id}`.
But It doesn't solved How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is not with your parent component, but with your child components

this might solve the problem:

```
root.addChild(<Person id="child1" key="child1" name="B" />);
root.addChild(<Person id="child2" key="child2" name="C" />);
root.addChild(<Person id="child3" key="child3" name="D" />);
```

but in my opinion you are approaching the problem in a very bad way - you shouldn't keep whole rendered elements in your `state`, only the data needed to render them and then in `render` you should create the tree

Comment: Then what is best way to add child?

Comment: @WebEngine by passing data structure, eg. `[{id:"child1", name:"B"}, {id:"child2", name:"C"}, {id:"child3", name: "D"}]` and then rendering children based on this data

Answer (score 1):

Your key just needs to be unique; why not set it to the value of *id*?

```
root.addChild(<Person id="child1" key="child1" name="B" />);
```

Comment: OP said he did it, but it seems that he have placed `key` on the wrong component